# Light with uniform spectograph?

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy, light-emitting-diodes

I've been looking for lights, namely LEDs as they seem to be a more controlled and reliable method of producing light (at least from my degree of familiarity), that can produce light at a very specific wavelength. From my research, an LED (or laser) with variable wavelength is either "not possible" or at least very uncommon, given such devices are designed for a specific wavelength range.

So it seemed to me that perhaps, instead of getting lights at specific wavelengths, a "white" light could be obtained and a prism-like device could be used to constrain or otherwise isolate specific wavelengths. However, the issue then arises that not all white light is created equal.

[image: spectographs of various light sources]

The above image is of course the relative spectographs of various light sources. Even daylight is not uniform in its light, having the most of cyan and least of violet (according to the image). For the sake of consistent intensity between wavelengths, it would seem most optimal to me to have a light source with a uniform spectograph. I.e.:

[image: uniform spectograph example]

My question becomes: is such a light source possible, and furthermore accessible?

The way in which to generate light I'm familiar with is the excitation of electrons of specific atoms such that, upon reverting to a lower energy state, the electron "emits" a wave of light (photon) at a given wavelength (I'm not aware of there being any other way, but it's always possible that I'm ignorant in various areas). As such, I'd expect the wavelengths possible are limited by the energy states available of the electrons being excited, of which I'm not familiar with any materials or combinations thereof that would make a uniform distribution (but then, I'm also not deeply familiar with creating light-producing devices in the first place).

I'm interested in any expertise people may have regarding the production of light, including areas in which I may be ignorant and/or mistaken. Thank you.

Comment: Re, "a prism-like device could be used to constrain or otherwise isolate specific wavelengths" That has a name: It's called a [_monochromator_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromator).

Comment: Re, "...not all white light is created equal." The usual solution for that is a calibration curve that compensates for the non-uniformity of the spectrum of the light source.

Comment: What is a "uniform" spectrograph. A flat $P(\lambda)$ is not a flat $P(\nu)$ is not a flat $P(N_{\gamma})$.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What are you going to use your tunable light source for?

Comment: @SolomonSlow huh. I'd researched monochromators before, but I guess I wasn't certain you could vary the wavelength, so it largely slipped my mind. Perhaps the exact answer I'm looking for. Regarding calibration curves, I don't believe I've heard of that before. I'll add that to my research list. Thank you.

Comment: @JEB My knowledge regarding spectographs is likely barely beyond surface level, so I can't say I'm familiar with the terms you're using or how they apply. I'll definitely try to explore those, though.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was mostly aiming to explore ways to describe color in a manner not constricted to existing color spaces, and how it might be able to be described in a manner that could even work in digital formats (so a monitor might not be restricted to the "small" RGB gamut). It's all hobbyistic for now, and the potential tangents are arguably extensive, so it's most basically for exploring how the eyes perceive various combinations of color curves, and ways to potentially describe it (considering but not limiting to existing color spaces).

Comment: A source that is always monochromatic (but tunable) will only be able to produce a very limited (a single 1-d path through the full colorspace of human perception) gamut of colors. An RGB LED (really 3 LEDs with different colors) will produce a wider gamut.

Comment: @ThePhoton very true. My intent was moreso to use more than one monochromator (or similar) and observe how they combine. RGB effectively *is* 3 monochromatic lights being combined in different intensities. I just dislike how RGB can't hit violet (or anything short of blue) nor anything long of the red light's wavelength, and furthermore is fairly small compared to CIELAB and other color spaces (missing several oranges, greens, etc.). I'm curious about exploring a definition of color that isn't necessarily limited to 3 dimensions (unless that would happen to work best) as most color spaces do.

Comment: I'm not a colorimetry expert, but isn't color limited to 3 dimensions because the human eye only has 3 different receptor types?

Comment: @ThePhoton Using the cones as the basis for color dimensions is effectively where RGB comes from, but because the cones respond to **ranges** of wavelengths, no 3 monochromatic colors can produce every color the eyes can see. Some miss more colors than others, so RGB was chosen (tmk) due to a combination of minimizing missed colors and maximizing efficiency/simplicity in computation using 3 color primaries. CIELAB also uses 3 dimensions, but tmk is not defined based on the cones like RGB tries to. CIELAB variables also have a more non-linear relation to each other compared to RGB.